# How to set inoremap/nnoremap to "command key" on Vim?

Tags: macos, vim

I would like to assign operation to a command key in Vim.
Aren't any methods?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Supposing you are on a Mac, **you can't map the command key in vim *when it runs in a terminal emulator*, only in the MacVim *GUI***.

If you are using the MacVim GUI, your mappings should use `<D-…>` as in `nnoremap <D-l> <C-w>l`. But it's not a very good idea for many reasons among them those listed in [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9451636/546861).

Use `<leader>`, as in `nnoremap <leader>l <C-w>l`, instead.

See `:help leader` and `:help key-notation`.

Comment: Thank you! It succeeded by <D-...>

Comment: Happy to help, but please consider using something else.