# How to map mac command key in vim?

Tags: macos, vim

I want to map my NERDTREE toggle to **Cmd + space** but I don't know what character represents Mac's command key in .vimrc. I searched and found that we can use 'D' to represent cmd key from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528151/how-to-map-command-key-when-configurate-vimrc) link, but it doesn't work.
BTW I am using vim from the terminal not MacVim.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9499124/2836621

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is true that `<D-` maps to <kbd>command</kbd> key. You can see it by `:help <D-`.

However, this will not work in your `vim`+`terminal`. It only works in `MacVim`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498653/how-to-set-inoremap-nnoremap-to-command-key-on-vim)

The best shot for your intention is to map the combination as hex code, sending to terminal.

Still I will not recommend doing this. <kbd>command</kbd> is too important for mac os environment. For example, anyone uses an input method can't map it to <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.\

Please consider using the usual method here: `<leader>`.

Answer (score 34):

iTerm2 can do this - here I mapped command enter to :wq

[image]

Comment: finally `cmd+/` can comment-out stuff!

Comment: Send text with "vim" special Chars will also take vim key map style syntax, ie. "\<D-S>". The leading backslash is required, see https://iterm2-discuss.narkive.com/2T4MenGn/send-text-with-vim-special-chars-sends-literal-chars

Answer (score 5):

With IdeaVim you can use: `<M-*>`, for example `<M-c>` means Cmd + c

Comment: What does the * stand for? Could you go into a little more detail, thank you.

Comment: I think it just means "any key you want"

Comment: @SerkanSipahi yes, * stands for any key you want. `<M-c>` means Cmd + c.

Answer (score 4):

An example in iTerm 2 of mapping CMD+p to vim's Meta P to call :CtrlP command.
This has the advantage that Meta is usually not used for anything so it won't clash with existing commands.

[image: iTerm key config for CMD+p]

And on .vimrc you'd add

```
map <M-p> :CtrlP<CR>
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that you are using Iterm2. Maybe mention that in bold ? Great answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I updated the answer with that fact.

Comment: However command+P in MacOS is command for "Print" iterm2 also use it